# How to ignore some kinds of messages in a Kafka Streams Application that reads and writes different event types from the same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, avro, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Let's suppose a Spring Cloud Stream application creates a `KStream` from an `order topic`. It is interested in `OrderCreated {"id":x, "productId": y, "customerId": z}` events. Once one arrives, it processes it and generates an output event `OrderShipped {"id":x, "productId": y, "customerName": <, "customerAddress": z}` to the same `order topic`.

The problem I am facing is that since it reads and writes from/to the same topic, the Kafka Stream application is trying to process its own writes, which doesn't make sense.

How could I prevent this application from processing the events it generates?

**UPDATE:** As Artem Bilan and sobychako point out I had considered using `KStream.filter()` but there are some details that make me doubt about how to deal with this:

Right now the KStream application looks like this:

```
interface ShippingKStreamProcessor {
    ...
    @Input("order")
    fun order(): KStream<String, OrderCreated>

    @Output("output")
    fun output(): KStream<String, OrderShipped>
```

**KStream Configuration**

```
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    fun process(..., @Input("order") order: KStream<Int, OrderCreated>): KStream<Int, OrderShipped> {
```

Both order and output bindings point at the order topic as destination.

**OrderCreated class:**

```
data class OrderCreated(var id: Int?, var productId: Int?, var customerId: Int?) {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null)
}
```

**OrderShipped class**

```
data class OrderShipped(var id: Int?, var productId: Int?, var customerName: String?, var customerAddress: String?) {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null, null)
}
```

I am using **JSON** as message format so messages look like this:

- INPUT - OrderCreated:  `{"id":1, "productId": 7,"customerId": 20}`
- OUTPUT - OrderShipped: `{"id":1, "productId": 7, "customerName": "X", "customerAddress": "Y"}`

**I'm looking for the best approach to filter out unwanted messages** considering this:

If I just use `KStream.filter()` right now, when I get `{"id":1, "productId": 7, "customerName": "X", "customerAddress": "Y"}` my `KStream<Int, OrderCreated>` would unmarshal an OrderShipped event as an OrderCreated object with some null fields: `OrderCreated(id:1, productId: 7, customerId: null)`. Checking on null fields doesn't sound robust.

A **possible solution** could be to add another field, `eventType = OrderCreated|OrderShipped`, to every kind of message/class that uses that topic. Even in this case, I would end up having an OrderCreated class (remember KStream< Int,OrderCreated >) with an attribute eventType=OrderShipped. **This looks like an ugly workaround**. Any idea to improve it?

Is there another, more automatic way to deal with this? For instance, would another kind of serialization (**AVRO**?) prevent messages from being processed if they don't comply with the expected schema (OrderCreated)?
This way of supporting multiple schemas (event types) in the same topic seems to be a good practice according to this article: https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/ 
However it's not clear how unmarshall/deserialize different types.

Comment: Why `KStream.filter()` doesn't work for you? Since everything is in Kafka topic those `OrderShipped` will still be available for other consumers on the topic.

Comment: As @ArtemBilan mentioned, that should be something that can be controlled by a `filter`. If you can share some more code, we can take a look.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Kafka's record headers to store the type of the record. See [KIP-82](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers). You can set the headers in [`ProducerRecord`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html).

The processing would be as follows:

1. Read a `stream` of type `KStream<Integer, Bytes>` with value serde `Serdes.BytesSerde` from the topic.
2. Use [`KStream#transformValues()`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transformValues-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueTransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) to filter and create the objects. More specifically, within `transformValues()` you can access the [`ProcessorContext`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html) which gives you access to the record headers that contain the information about the type of the record. Then:

   - If the type is `OrderShipped`, return `null`.
   - Otherwise create an `OrderCreated` object from the `Bytes` object and return it.

For a solution with AVRO, you might want to have a look at the following docs

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html

Comment: I think your solution could work out fine but I have a doubt about it,  transformValues(ValueTransformerSupplier<? super V,? extends VR> valueTransformerSupplier,
                                   java.lang.String... stateStoreNames)
 is a stateful operation and it expects the state store names in the transform method, is it necessary to pass a store name or it can be omitted...

Comment: The state store can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I've accepted Bruno's answer as a valid way to solve this problem. However I think I've come up with a more straightforward/logical way using a hierachy of events annotated with  `JsonTypeInfo`.

First you need a base class for the Order events and specify all subclasses. Note that there will be a type property added to the JSON document that will help Jackson marshal/unmarshal the DTO:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(value = [
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OrderCreatedEvent::class, name = "orderCreated"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OrderShippedEvent::class, name = "orderShipped")
])
abstract class OrderEvent

data class OrderCreatedEvent(var id: Int?, var productId: Int?, var customerId: Int?) : OrderEvent() {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null)
}

data class OrderShippedEvent(var id: Int?, var productId: Int?, var customerName: String?, var customerAddress: String?) : OrderEvent () {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null, null)
}
```

With this in place a producer of OrderCreatedEvent objects will generate a message like this:

`key: 1 value: {"type":"orderCreated","id":1,"productId":24,"customerId":1}`

Now is the turn of the KStream. I have changed the signature to `KStream<Int, OrderEvent>` since it can receive OrderCreatedEvent or OrderShippedEvent. In the next two lines...

```
orderEvent.filter { _, value -> value is OrderCreatedEvent }
                .map { key, value -> KeyValue(key, value as OrderCreatedEvent) }
```

... I filter to retain only messages of the OrderCreatedEvent class and map them to convert the `KStream<Int, OrderEvent>` into a `KStream<Int, OrderCreatedEvent>`

Full KStream logic:

```
@StreamListener
@SendTo("output")
fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<Int, Customer>, @Input("order") orderEvent: KStream<Int, OrderEvent>): KStream<Int, OrderShippedEvent> {

        val intSerde = Serdes.IntegerSerde()
        val customerSerde = JsonSerde<Customer>(Customer::class.java)
        val orderCreatedSerde = JsonSerde<OrderCreatedEvent>(OrderCreatedEvent::class.java)

        val stateStore: Materialized<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>> =
                Materialized.`as`<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("customer-store")
                        .withKeySerde(intSerde)
                        .withValueSerde(customerSerde)

        val customerTable: KTable<Int, Customer> = input.groupByKey(Serialized.with(intSerde, customerSerde))
                .reduce({ _, y -> y }, stateStore)


        return (orderEvent.filter { _, value -> value is OrderCreatedEvent }
                .map { key, value -> KeyValue(key, value as OrderCreatedEvent) }
                .selectKey { _, value -> value.customerId } as KStream<Int, OrderCreatedEvent>)
                .join(customerTable, { orderIt, customer ->
                    OrderShippedEvent(orderIt.id, orderIt.productId, customer.name, customer.address)
                }, Joined.with(intSerde, orderCreatedSerde, customerSerde))
                .selectKey { _, value -> value.id }
                //.to("order", Produced.with(intSerde, orderShippedSerde))
    }
```

After this process I'm generating a new message `key: 1 value: {"type":"orderShipped","id":1,"productId":24,"customerName":"Anna","customerAddress":"Cipress Street"}` into the order topic but this will be filtered out by the stream.

Comment: This works fine for me if all event types are known. However, any suggestions how to handle/ignore events of unknown type? For example there might be an `OrderDeletedEvent` which should be ignored by the consumer service because it's not relevant. In this case I don't want to include the additional, unnecessary `OrderDeletedEvent` class. One solution would be to log the error and continue processing by configuring `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`, but this means that all deserialization exceptions are ignored which might not be desirable.